# Make an active search with QlistWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to hide irrelevant results as I type into my search bar and once the search bar is cleared to show all items again in the listWidget.

I'm honestly not sure how to go about this as I am extremely new to programming (started 3 weeks ago). Currently I'm thinking I can do an if > then statement to hide the items but I don't know how to go about it using the findItems() method.

```
def searchItem(self):
    search_string = self.textEdit.toPlainText() """pulling the text from a text edit box"""
    items = self.listWidget.findItems(search_string, Qt.MatchContains)
    for item in items:
        if item:
            item.setHidden(False)
        else:
            item.setHidden(True)
```

Currently this basically does nothing. if i add Print(item.text()) it only prints the relevant items making me think I'm on the right track.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is iterate over all the items in the QListWidgets, not just the ones that match the text, and hide it if the item is not in the items that match.

```py
def searchItem(self):
    search_string = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
    match_items = self.listWidget.findItems(search_string, Qt.MatchContains)
    for i in range(self.listWidget.count()):
        it = self.listWidget.item(i)
        it.setHidden(it not in match_items)
```